# How to upload multiple files with jodd-http?

Tags: jodd

How do I upload muliple files in the same request using jodd HTTP?

I've tried something like the following but only the first file was posted.

```
HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest
        .post("http://srv:8080/api/dlapp/add-file-entry")
        .form(
            "title", "test",
            "description", "Upload test",
            "file", new File("d:\\a.jpg.zip"),
            "file", new File("d:\\b.jpg.zip")
        );

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpRequest.send();
```

Comment: did you try with different parameter name `file`, e.g. `file1` and `file2`?

Comment: @igr Yes tried with `file1`, `file2` same effect only the first file was uploaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the correct code. You simply add file parameters:

```java
HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.post("localhost:8173/echo")
        .form(
            "title", "test",
            "description", "Upload test",
            "file1", temp1,
            "file2", temp2
        );
```

Nothing more, nothing less. There is [the testcase](https://github.com/oblac/jodd/blob/master/jodd-http/src/test/java/jodd/http/HttpUploadTest.java) that checks just that.

The easiest way to check is to fireup e.g. [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) on your local machine and simply inspect the request; there must be two files blocks in it.

Is it possible that your serverside, for some reason is not accepting files?

Do you use the latest version (v5.0.x)?

p.s. if you are sending two files, please use two different parameter names (e.g. `file1`, `file2`).

Comment: OK I was on jodd version 3.6.6, switched to the current version and files are uploaded as expected - thanks!